# In a differential equation, would you call "y" a variable or a function?

Tags: functions, differential

In a differential equation, would you call "y" a variable or a function? Or can you call it both things?

Comment: Both - it's an unknown function!

Comment: Like @SeanRoberson said, I would refer to it as an “unknown function”

Comment: But if one wrote f(x) instead of y, then you wouldn't call f(x) a variable but a function?

Comment: You would still call it an “unknown function.” I may be wrong but I think generally a variable refers to a symbol representing a number (not a function).

Comment: It is a dependent variable; it can serve as a variable while being itself dependent of another variable.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/84221

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/115416

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/307947

Comment: @Clara0172. $f(x)$ isn't a function; it's the value at $x$ of the function $f$.